# Home network with one modem and two routers in series

Tags: router, internet, home-networking

I have internet connection going from the modem to a tplink router. I have WiFi and internet connection. Now I would like to connect a Linksys router from a LAN output port of the first to the WAN port of the second, and create a second WiFi network, also connected to the internet. A friend of mine made it work in the past, but has suddenly stopped working (the lights went out or something). Could anyone please help me with the config's of both routers? Thank you

Comment: Did you research this at all? Just log into the 2nd Router, give it an IP address that is different than 1st Router but within the same subnet, setup WiFi, disable DHCP, then connect your feed from a LAN port on R1 to a LAN port on R2... Done. This process is well documented all over the internet, and here dozens of times, a few Google searches would find this answer in seconds.

Comment: @acejavelin. First of all thank you for the answer. Second, if you see my profile (specially on stackoverflow), you see that I'm not new to stackexchange and know the usual rules. I searched on the interwebs and tried several different setups. None of them worked. Thing is I don't understand half of what I'm doing. That's y I came up to superuser so someone expert in the subject could give me a "step by step", as great answers around here usually are.

Answer (score 0):

Most home networks are best off with only a single box acting as a NAT gateway (router) and DHCP server. If your modem has those features and you can't turn it off there, then set up your wireless "routers" to act as simple APs rather than NAT gateways.

Many wireless routers don't let you turn off NAT, so you just have to turn off their DHCP server feature, and plug their LAN port into your home LAN, and leave their WAN port empty. That way they automatically bridge packets from LAN to WLAN transparently.